# How can I run automatically tests generated by spec'ed functions with `lein test`?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I have spec'ed functions so I can run automatically generated tests using [check](https://clojure.github.io/spec.alpha/clojure.spec.test.alpha-api.html#clojure.spec.test.alpha/check). How can I run these tests using `lein test`?

I'm trying

```
(deftest check-suggest-connections
  (is (= nil (spectest/summarize-results (spectest/check `suggest-connections)))))
```

in my `core_test.clj` but I'm getting a

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Syntax error compiling at (clojure/test/check/clojure_test.cljc:95:1).
Caused by: clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: Syntax error compiling at (clojure/test/check/clojure_test.cljc:95:1).
#:clojure.error{:phase :compile-syntax-check, :line 95, :column 1, :source "clojure/test/check/clojure_test.cljc"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work around described by Alex Miller in [here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/2173)

Just needed to add `:monkeypatch-clojure-test false` in `project.clj`.